# Create product with custom option using rest api

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, rest-api

I am trying to create simple product with custom option using rest api but custom option is not saving with product endpoint `rest/V1/products`. anything missing here

Here is my request body

```json
    {
    "product": {
        "sku": "test_simple_product3",
        "name": "Test Simple Product",
        "attribute_set_id": 4,
        "price": 25,
        "status": 1,
        "visibility": 1,
        "type_id": "simple",
        "weight": "0.5"
    },
    "custom_attributes": [
        
        {
            "attribute_code": "has_options",
            "value": 1
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "required_options",
            "value": 1
        }
    ],
    "options": [
        {
            "product_sku": "test_simple_product3",
            "title": "Scelta",
            "type": "checkbox",
            "sort_order": null,
            "is_require": true,
            "price_type": null,
            "values": [
                {
                    "title": "A3",
                    "sort_order": 1,
                    "price": 7.35,
                    "price_type": "fixed",
                    "sku": "A3"
                },
                {
                    "title": "A4",
                    "sort_order": 1,
                    "price": 9.45,
                    "price_type": "fixed",
                    "sku": "A4"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation in Redoc https://magento.redoc.ly/2.3.6-admin/tag/products#operation/catalogProductRepositoryV1SavePost,  the main key ***'product'*** holds all the product information, including the attribute values and the options definition.

---

Your payload should look like this

```json
{
   "product":{
      "sku":"test_simple_product3",
      "name":"Test Simple Product",
      "attribute_set_id":4,
      "price":25,
      "status":1,
      "visibility":1,
      "type_id":"simple",
      "weight":"0.5",
      "custom_attributes":[
         {
            "attribute_code":"has_options",
            "value":1
         },
         {
            "attribute_code":"required_options",
            "value":1
         }
      ],
      "options":[
         {
            "product_sku":"test_simple_product3",
            "title":"Scelta",
            "type":"checkbox",
            "sort_order":null,
            "is_require":true,
            "price_type":null,
            "values":[
               {
                  "title":"A3",
                  "sort_order":1,
                  "price":7.35,
                  "price_type":"fixed",
                  "sku":"A3"
               },
               {
                  "title":"A4",
                  "sort_order":1,
                  "price":9.45,
                  "price_type":"fixed",
                  "sku":"A4"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: what was wrong in my request body can you explain please

Comment: i think i just did :) the 'product' key should include 'custom_attributes' and 'options' and NOT be added at the same level with them. just compare my code with yours and you will see.

Comment: Ohh thanks for pointing me

Comment: you're welcome, no problem :)

Comment: when try to create `field` type option it won't work can you help me please.

Comment: I am passing like this "options": [
        {
            "product_sku": "test_simple_product3",
            "title": "Add Your Name (Max 15 Characters)",
            "type": "field",
            "sort_order": 1,
            "is_require": false,
            "price": 10,
            "price_type": "fixed",
            "sku": "Personalized",
            "max_characters": 15
        }
    ]

Comment: I would suggest you open a new question as what you are currently asking is offtopic. Thanks

Comment: can you answer here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/334959/create-product-with-custom-option-field-type-using-rest-api-not-saving