# Create product with custom option (Field type ) using rest api not saving

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, rest-api

I am trying to create simple product with custom option(Field type) using rest api but custom option is not saving with product endpoint `rest/V1/products`.

request body

```
    {
    "product": {
        "sku": "test_simple_product3",
        "name": "Test Simple Product",
        "attribute_set_id": 4,
        "price": 25,
        "status": 1,
        "visibility": 1,
        "type_id": "simple",
        "weight": "0.5"
    },
    "custom_attributes": [
        {
            "attribute_code": "has_options",
            "value": 1
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "required_options",
            "value": 1
        }
    ],
    "options": [
        {
            "product_sku": "test_simple_product3",
            "title": "Add Your Name (Max 15 Characters)",
            "type": "field",
            "sort_order": 1,
            "is_require": false,
            "price": 10,
            "price_type": "fixed",
            "sku": "Personalized",
            "max_characters": 15
        }
    ]
  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this payload instead:

```json
{
   "product":{
      "sku":"test_simple_product3",
      "name":"Test Simple Product",
      "attribute_set_id":4,
      "price":25,
      "status":1,
      "visibility":1,
      "type_id":"simple",
      "weight":"0.5",
      "custom_attributes":[
         {
            "attribute_code":"has_options",
            "value":1
         },
         {
            "attribute_code":"required_options",
            "value":1
         }
      ],
      "options":[
         {
            "product_sku":"test_simple_product3",
            "title":"Add Your Name (Max 15 Characters)",
            "type":"field",
            "sort_order":1,
            "is_require":false,
            "price":10,
            "price_type":"fixed",
            "sku":"Personalized",
            "max_characters":15
         }
      ]
   }
}
```